# Countable.js get in Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter

I'm new to JavaScript and jQuery, I found [this](http://sacha.me/Countable/) plugin which allows me to count the amount of words in a textbox. I was able to implement this into my form. However, what I would like to do is if the user adds more than 25 words it will give me an error.

I am using [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) in my form to validate.

The code I have in my Javascript is;

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('#textarea').simplyCountable({
    counter: '#words',
    countType: 'words',
    maxCount: 25,
    overClass: 'over',
    countDirection: 'up'
});

var area = document.getElementById('textarea')
Countable.live(area, function (counter) {
    console.log(counter)
    })
```

});

When I view this on my page, I see the following;

[image]

My question is how can I get to Object > words?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
Countable.live($('#textarea'), function (counter) {
      var totalWOrdsCount = counter.words;
  })
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, when I added in your code, it throws an error "Countable: No valid elements were found".

Comment: $('#textarea') will return a jQuery object, while Countable expects a HTML DOM object. In order to return the HTML DOM object from jQuery, you need to pass $('#textarea')[0].